# How do I add a boolean that can only have one true for one column name of the same type?

Tags: mysql, boolean

I have a table called computer and a column office_id, computer_name, server.
I was each office ID to have only one computer that is the server. so if i have multiple computers in an office. Only one computer in the office is the server and a server is required. there can't be an office with no server.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to implement this in the `Computers` table, then you will need to use a trigger in MySQL.  Other databases support things like filtered indexes and computed columns making this unnecessary, but not MySQL.

Instead, just add a column to your `Offices` table:

```
create table Offices (
    . . . ,
    ServerId int not null,
    Foreign key (ServerId) references Computers(ComputerId)
);
```

This will guarantee that each office has one server.  You might need a trigger to guarantee that the `OfficeId` in the `Computers` table matches the `OfficeId` in the `Offices` table, though.